# Where can I find the Ubuntu WebApps source code?

Tags: source-code, webapps

[This article](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/259502/canonical_equips_ubuntu_with_desktop_web_apps.html) mentions the following:

> Ubuntu WebApps runs only on the Unity desktop interface, and its code will be available as open source on the Canonical Launchpad project management service.

The article also mentions that WebApps is a "plugin for the Firefox browser". Where can I find its source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the code section of its [Launchpad projects page](https://code.launchpad.net/webapps).